How to cut intersecting circles in Inkscape
I have the image on the left, and I want to obtain the image on the right by deleting some lines to create a white area. For this, I want to obtain intersecting lines and then delete them.
Thank you for your help.


Hi. Welcome to GDSE. You can use the shape builder tool for this in Inkscape see example here

Thank you the shape builder did the trick!

By the way you need to update to 1.3 to use the shape builder.

In Inkscape 1.3+ you can use the new Shape Builder Tool from the toolbar.


Design your circles and select them all.
With all selected choose the Shape Builder tool from the toolbar.
Drag and drop over the "cells" to create additive shapes.
Each set of cells you continuously drag over generate a single shape once finished. Interrupt the dragging operation whenever you want to create a new shape you wish to color differently after finishing.
Press Enter when finished.


This is a destructive process, so if you want to keep a copy of your line circles to use as an overlay, make a duplicate copy of them beforehand and set them aside or put them in a separate layer.
